# print 2 numbers and skip 2 numbers in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to figure out a way to print some numbers in an array. I have an array[**0,1**,2,3,**4,5**,6] and I would like print the numbers 0,1,4,5. Is it possible to create a loop that can read the first two numbers skipping the next two and reading the following two numbers.

Comment: Is there a particular language you are targetting?

Comment: im currently programming in c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use modulo operation on current index to check if this number belongs to "print 2" or "skip 2":

```c
int a[17];
int length = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
    if (i % 4 < 2) 
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

So, for `i` equal to 0 and 1, it will output value. For `i == 2` and `i == 3`, the condition will result to false. Next, it will take 4, `4 % 4` is 0, and it will repeat it every 4 steps.

Answer (score 0):

## **Pseudocode:**

```
arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
skip = 2;
print = true;

while(i < arr.length){
   for(j = 0; j < skip; ++j){
      if(print){
         output arr[i];
      }
      
      //increment array counter
      i++;
      
      //toggle print bool
      print = !print
   }
}
```

Just change the value of skip to set the interval, and set `print = false` if you'd like it to skip the first `skip` entries